# Laravel 7 password reset

Tags: php, laravel, change-password

I have the following ForgottenPasswordController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\v1;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset emails and
    | includes a trait which assists in sending these notifications from
    | your application to your users. Feel free to explore this trait.
    |
    */

    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    protected function sendResetLinkResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return response(['message' => $response]);
    }

    protected function sendResetLinkFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return response(['message' => $response], 422);
    }
}
```

and the following ResetPasswordController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\v1;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    protected function sendResetResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return response(['message' => $response]);
    }

    protected function sendResetFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return response(['error' => $response], 422);
    }


    /**
     * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
}
```

When I make an axios reqeust to the forgotPasswordController I get the email delivered as expected. When I then submit my new password, along with the email address and token back to ResetPasswordController I get the following response,

> error: "passwords.token"

on further ispection at the point where a reset is requested no email or token is saved in the password_resets table, why would this be, I have changed nothing in the Auth scaffolding via `laravel/ui --auth` other than make the response from 2 methods be json and not blade views.

Comment: Did you run `php artisan migrate` after your `composer require laravel/ui`?

Comment: Also, you have to translate response message yourself if you are overriding these methods: `return response(['message' => trans($response)]);`

Answer (score 0):

go to `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker.php`
you will see:

```
const INVALID_TOKEN = 'passwords.token';
```

Now just change your desire CONST. Happy Coding